# Modify CSS Using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css

I want something like below code should convert to

```
#A1, #A2, #A3, #A4{
   float: left;
   clear: left;
   width: 300px;
   margin: 15px;
}
```

to

```
#A1, #A2, #A3, #A4{
   float: left;
   clear: left;
   width: 400px;
   margin: 15px;
}
```

and that `Width` property value should be dynamic. That should come from javascript. How can we do that?

Comment: Have you tried googling this?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
document.getElementById("id").style.width = "900px";
```

to change the widths of each element found by id.  You'd ideally do this for A1, A2, A3, and A4.

Answer (score 2):

***EDIT***: Okay fine, here's the pure DOM version:

```
function changeWidths(ids, width) {
    for(var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
       document.getElementById(ids[i]).style.width = width + "px";
    }
}

changeWidths(["A1", "A2", "A3", "A4"], 400);
```

JavaScript doesn't act on the actual CSS text directly, it acts on the element's style. If we use something like JQuery, we can modify the width of all the ID's you mentioned like so:

```
$("#A1, #A2, #A3, #A4").css({"width": 400});
```

Comment: It's easier  to use the raw DOM API for this if you're not already using jQuery.

Comment: @Jeremy Updated my code. The reason why I showed the JQuery version was because comprehension wise it better matches the selectors in the CSS.

Comment: @Jeremy It's easier to use jQuery. No ifs.

Comment: @onteria_: I understand, and I didn't downvote. But @Suraj didn't mention jQuery at all. It's definitely cleaner, but the OP shouldn't have to explicitly exclude jQuery in order to not get jQuery-based answers. That said, I think supplying a jQuery solution after a straight-JS/DOM solution is perfectly fine when jQuery might *actually* be helpful.

Comment: @Jeremy I think the JQuery version concise and more flexible, versus this specific function taking a list of IDs. What happens when you want to select by classes? Element names? This function has to be expanded more to handle the extra requirements. Here I can use the flexibility of CSS selectors to handle more cases.

Comment: @onteria_ ... really.... more concise? https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.js ... jquery turns this from a 5 line solution, into a 8941 line solution.

Comment: @jondavidjohn I meant the resulting function call, not the JQuery library, please don't put words into my mouth.

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementById("A1").style.width = "400px";
```